# Laptop hibernates as soon as power cord disconnected

Tags: shutdown, battery

On an [Asus K550](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-K550-Series.127578.0.html) laptop, when I remove the power cable, Ubuntu claims the power is critically low and starts to hibernate. The battery was fully charged and before going into hibernation, I did see I had 55 minutes left of battery power. I have even tried replacing battery with a brand new replacement, which did not solve the problem.

Comment: 1) Do you still have Windows on that laptop? 2) If you still have Windows, does the same thing happen? 3) Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 4) Have you installed a power management app, such as TLP? https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/18/quick-tip-improve-battery-life-ubuntu-18-04-higher/ Please click [edit] and add your answers to the qiuestion. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].